# AWS Cognito to authenticate App users and retrieve settings from MySQL database

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, mobile, architecture, amazon-cognito

I am doing some research for a mobile app I want to develop, and was wondering whether I could get feedback on the following architecture. Within my future app users should be able to authenticate and register themselves via the mobile app and retrieve and use their settings after a successful authentication.

What I am looking for is an architecture in which user accounts are managed by AWS Cognito, but all application related information is stored in a MySQL database hosted somewhere else.

Why host the database outside of AWS? Because of high costs / vendor lock-in / for the sake of learning about architecture rather than going all-in on AWS or Azure

Why not build the identity management myself? Because in the end I want to focus on the App and don't spent a lot of energy on something that AWS can already provide me with (yeah I know, not quite in line with my last argument above, but otherwise all my time goes into database AND IAM)

One of my assumptions in this design (please correct me if I am wrong) is that it is only possible to retrieve data from a MySQL database with 'fixed credentials'. Therefore, I don't want the app (the user's device) to make these queries (but do this on the server instead) as the credentials to the database would otherwise be stored on the device.

Also, to make it (nearly) impossible for users to run queries on the database with a fake identity, I want the server to retrieve the User ID from AWS Cognito (rather than using the ID token from the device) and use this in the SQL query. This, should protect the service from a fake user ID injection from the device/user.

Are there functionalities I have missed in any of these components that could make my design less complicated or which could improve the flow?

[image: architecture design]

Answer (score 0):

Is that API (the one in the step 3) managed by the AWS API Gateway? If so, your cognito user pool can be set as [Authorizer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-integrate-with-cognito.html) in your AWS API Gateway, then the gateway will take care automatically of the token verification (Authorizers enable you to control access to your APIs using Amazon Cognito User Pools or a Lambda function).

You can also do the [token verification in a Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-use-lambda-authorizer.html) if you need to verify something else in the token.

Regarding to the connection between NodeJS (assuming that is an AWS lambda) that will work fine, but keep in mind the security as your customers data will travel outside AWS, and try to use tools like [AWS Secret Manager](https://aws.amazon.com/secrets-manager/) to keep your database passwords safe and rotate them from time to time in your lambda.

Comment: Thanks for the input! Seems I have some homework for the Sunday ;). In this design I was planning on making my own API on the server: one that consumes the access token and returns the user ID and settings. Regarding the server: I intend to build my own server instance. However I will definitively have a look at the possibilities within the AWS API Gateway and Lambda. What are, according to you, the advantages of using AWS managed services as compared to make these custom? (I am quite price focused in this phase of the project as the time to market will be long)

Comment: With Lambda you only pay for the time your function executes, so I think that is a good solution for the logic that you want to implement (query a DB and return the data). Lambda autoscalates automatically so you don't have to pay to provisioning heavy servers or spend time configuring and patching servers, if you want to calculate costs you can use the AWS calculator: https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/pricing/